# config setting in package.json file under scripts

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, package.json

I noticed

```
"ng:serve": "cross-env-shell ng serve --open --host=$HOSTNAME --disableHostCheck -c=dev",
```

in the package.json file under scripts. I was wondering where the flags (**--host, disableHostCheck, -c**) come from? Are they related to webpack-dev-server or specific to Angular? Is there any document where I can find a list of such flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags for ng serve are here ..

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve

--open Opens the url in default browser

Basically, when the dev server has started it opens a browser window automatically with the correct URL for the app.

--host

Host to listen on

--disable-host-check

Don't verify connected clients are part of allowed hosts.

--configuration (alias: -c)

Specify the configuration to use. Configurations are defined in angular.json (Angular 6) under the "configurations" property. They used to be called environments previously. Here is an example entry from angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
  "dan": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.dan.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and to use this configuration I would run with:

```
ng serve --configuration=dan
```

the configuration files define app level variables. A typical example being the api endpoint to make requests to, e.g. apiUurl: 'http://localhost:9600/api/'